# Criteria for displaying top % this week vs. month vs. quarter vs. year vs all time

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

When viewing a user's profile, it shows where the user ranks in the leagues.  For example, my profile currently shows "top 0.07% this year".

I was under the impression that the criteria to display "this year" vs "this week", "this month", "this quarter", or "all time" was based on whichever is the lowest.  This doesn't however seem to be the case.

I'm currently ranked #206 this year.  However my weekly rank is currently #116 (0.04%), and my monthly is #80 (0.03%).  So it would seem that my profile should be displaying the month rank instead of the year rank.

So the question is, if it isn't the smallest of these numbers which gets display, what exactly is the criteria for choosing which one?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146516/what-does-top-4-this-month-mean/146518#146518 (which confirms the question as it is not consistent with what was previously stated although I can't find a definitive statement from an SE Dev or CM that confirms this behavior).